# Redo typing in OSX bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

In bash on OSX I can do `ctrl-_` to undo what I most recently typed. Is there a corresponding redo command?

Comment: I've done a quick look in readline(3) man page and I can't found nothing about redo command/short-cut. readline(3) is the library responsible by shortcuts and historic feature in bash. If you are interested, you could have a look at the manual here http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3. There are all defaults shortcuts listed in this man page.

Comment: @BrunoCoimbra: looks like there might be nothing, but thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 5):

`ctrl-y` is the Readline 'yank' command which retrieves the kill buffer.  `ctrl-u` kills from the point to the beginning of the line (similar to OSX/bash `ctrl-_` which clears the whole line).  The Emacs-like Readline bindings are enabled in bash and a subset are enabled in many other places (browser search bars etc).

- `ctrl-u` kill from start of line to insertion point
- `ctrl-k` kill from insertion point to end of line
- `ctrl-w` kill previous word (and prepend to kill buffer)
- `ctrl-y` yank contents of kill buffer

Comment: I get different behavior (in Terminal in OS X and XTerm and Emacs in Fedora) - `ctrl-_` undoes whatever the last action was, and also `ctrl-y` retrieves any killed text, not just with `ctrl-u`. Still, I hadn't heard of `ctrl-y` before - thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer to say 'Readline' rather than 'Emacs', although many key bindings are shared, also to broaden the kill buffer's definition.  The Readline command `kill-whole-line`, which does the same as your `ctrl-_`, is [unbound](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_1.html) by default - I'd always wondered if there's a kill-whole-line command.  I use `ctrl-a-k` (_beginning-of-line kill-line_) to kill the whole line.

Comment: For me, `ctrl-_` doesn't kill the whole line, though -- it's an undo command

Comment: And it doesn't answer the question, either.